# Need to delete files (*.log.*) from subdirectories which has same name scattered in many root directory

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2012

I need to delete logs with extension `*.log.*`  exits in subfolder named `SessLogs`, `WorkflowLogs` under the root directory `d:\software\Bil`

Likewise I have the folders `SessLogs`, `WorkflowLogs` in many different named sub directories like `Bil` , how to achieve this I have a sample script created as shown below but it needs some update to it.

Directory structure for example

Software-->Wel-->""SessLogs"  and "WorkflowLogs"
Software-->Gim-->""SessLogs"  and "WorkflowLogs"
Software-->Ren-->""SessLogs"  and "WorkflowLogs"

```
$Path = "D:\software"
$Daysback = "-30"
$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$DatetoDelete = $CurrentDate.AddDays($Daysback)
get-childitem "D:\software*" -include "*.*" -force -recurse |where-object { (-not $_.PSIsContainer) -and ($_.creationtime -lt $DatetoDelete) } |remove-item -whatif
```

Comment: Do you want to delete every file that has the word logs in it, from every subfolder named  SessLogs or WorkFlowLogs under D:\Software\Bil? Are there any requirements as to the age of the file, or you just want to delete everything?

Comment: Hi Robbie, Need to delete files with extensions *.log like 6 months before from SessLogs and WorkFlowLogs directory wich resides under many root directories like Bil or Wel or Gim or Rin.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your requirement correctly, but if I do, you already had it. What I changed:

- When using `Get-Childitem` with `recurse` you do not need to add the Asterisk (*) at the end of the search path.
- Since you are looking for files that contain ".log.", just use that for the include parameter, not "*.*", which would search all files with a dot.
- you could also get rid of the `(-not $_.PSIsContainer)` if you know that none of your folders contain the string ".log." - but you can keep it to be sure.

So this should do the following:
 Get all items under D:\Software and all its subfolders that cointain the string ".log." in the name, that are no directories, and that were created 30 days in the past or before - then delete them.

```
$Path = "D:\software"
$Daysback = "-30"
$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$DatetoDelete = $CurrentDate.AddDays($Daysback)
get-childitem "D:\software" -include "*.log.*" -force -recurse |where-object { (-not $_.PSIsContainer) -and ($_.creationtime -lt $DatetoDelete) } |remove-item -whatif
```